# Defining Color band to recognize from sing layer raster in R

Tags: raster, r

I have a 2 part question, the first part was easy & is answered but I have one issue :

1) Load map in R and convert to Raster : Done

2) Tell R to only show a defined color band : NOT done

As you can see in my example map, it is a map of Namibia, and it is a single layer black and white map, with one blue dot.  The RGB code of this blue dot is:  Red == 14 , Green == 6, and Blue == 209

What I would like to do is tell R to Isolate this dot, and to leave out the rest, so in essence, when I plot the map, I have only the blue dot.

Here is my current code, and here is an example map.

```
rm(list=ls())

library(raster)

library(maps)

library(magick)

library(rgdal)

# working directory

setwd("Working here")
# load first image
Species_id<-1
Species_i <- image_read(paste("Species (", Species_id, ").png", sep=""))

Species_i_rotated<-image_rotate(Species_i,0)
image_write(Species_i_rotated, path = "Temporary.png", format = "png")

# create raster
Converted <- raster("Temporary.png", band=1)

#### This is where my problem needs solving
#This defines the threshold to classify where the dot on the image is present as 1
# While removing all the unwanted features

Converted<-Converted == 14 & Converted==6 & Converted==209
Converted[Converted==0]<-NA

plot(Converted) # I would like this to show only the blue dot.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead `image_read`, I used `readPNG` to solve your problem with less code:

```
# read image
img <- png::readPNG('~/path/to/image.png')
```

The output is an array with colors in 0 - 1 format.

```
# convert to raster
r <- brick(img)

raster::plotRGB(r, scale = 1)
```

[image]

```
# select blue color (R = 0%, G = 0%, B = 100%)    
plot(r[[1]] == 0 & r[[3]] == 1)
```

[image]

```
# Use it to mask
raster::plotRGB(mask(r, r[[1]] == 0 & r[[3]] == 1, maskvalue = 0), scale = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it works great! But..

Using the above map, I would like to associate that blue dot with a GPS point.  What I do is upload the map, convert it to a raster, define a coordinate system, plot the raster and I overlay a map of Namibia using this function

map(region="Namibia", add=T)      

From here, I generate a new map of Namibia, keeping that blue dot, and in the end, I will have the data of the GPS location. 
Is there a way, using my above code, of defining the threshold to classify where the dot on the image is present? (I assume this is with the RGB band values)

Comment: Use georeferencer plug-in from QGIS first

Comment: Hi @aldo_tapia:  I did not get a proper chance to say thanks for your help and your advice.   Looking forward to the day I know enough about this topic to help others myself

Comment: @Andy you're welcome. The best way to say 'thanks you' in this site is with upvotes or accepting answers.